# Is 1-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test a special case of 2-sample one?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

I'm reading Kolmogorov–Smirnov test from [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

1. One-sample case

> [image]
>   [image]

2. Two-sample case

> [image]

I try to deduce the one-sample test from two-sample test by choosing $m$ and the second sample $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_m)$ such that $$D_{n, m}=\sup _{x}\left|F_{1, n}(x)-F_{2, m}(x)\right| = D_{n}=\sup _{x}\left|F_{n}(x)-F(x)\right|$$

I'm unable to make $F_{2, m}= F$. Could you please elaborate on how to do so? Thank you so much!

Comment: It is not a special case, since $F_{2,m}$ is an empirical CDF whereas $F$ is some known parametric distribution...Do not try to create something new.